# Can I get a C++ Compiler to instantiate objects at compile time?

Tags: c++, optimization, gcc

I am writing some code that has a very large number of reasonably simple objects and I would like them the be created at compile time.  I would think that a compiler would be able to do this, but I have not been able to figure out how.

In *C* I could do the the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct data_s {
    int a;
    int b;
    char *c;
} info;

info list[] = {
    1, 2, "a",
    3, 4, "b",
};

main()
{
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < sizeof(list)/sizeof(*list); i++) {
     printf("%d %s\n", i, list[i].c);
   }
}
```

Using #C++* each object has it constructor called rather than just being layed out in memory.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Info {
    const int a;
    const int b;
    const char *c;
public:
    Info(const int, const int, const char *);
    const int get_a() { return a; };
    const int get_b() { return b; };
    const char *get_c() const { return c; };
};

Info::Info(const int a, const int b, const char *c) : a(a), b(b), c(c) {};

Info list[] = {
    Info(1, 2, "a"),
    Info(3, 4, "b"),
};

main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(list)/sizeof(*list); i++) {
        cout << i << " " << list[i].get_c() << endl;
    }
}
```

I just don't see what information is not available for the compiler to completely  instantiate these objects at compile time, so I assume I am missing something.

Comment: have a look at static classes or the singleton idom. Maybe that is what you are looking for in c++

Comment: What is wrong with the answers you got for [the same question on Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/165008/can-i-get-a-c-compiler-to-instantiate-objects-at-compile-time)?

Comment: @Najzero C++ has no static classes.

Comment: @DCoder: My answer to your question would be: "The C++ way to do this isn't mentioned". This assumes, of course, that the author mistyped the title which is relatively likely giving that the actual question clearly uses C++ and not C.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++ 2011 you can create objects at compile time. For this to happen, you need to make various things constant expressions, however:

1. The constructor needs to be declared `constexpr`.
2. The entity you declare needs to be declared `constexpr`.

Note, that nearly all your `const` qualifiers are either irrelevant or in the wrong location. Here is an example with the various correction and also actually demonstrating that the `list` array is initialized during compile time (by using members of it to define the values of an `enum`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

class Info {
    int a;
    int b;
    char const*c;

public:
    constexpr Info(int, int, char const*);
    constexpr int get_a() const { return a; }
    constexpr int get_b() const { return b; }
    constexpr char const*get_c() const { return c; }
};

constexpr Info::Info(int a, int b, char const*c)
  : a(a), b(b), c(c) {}

constexpr Info list[] = {
    Info(1, 2, "a"),
    Info(3, 4, "b"),
};

enum {
    b0 = list[0].get_b(),
    b1 = list[1].get_b()
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "b0=" << b0 << " b1=" << b1 << "\n";
    for (Info const* it(list), *end(list); it != end; ++it) {
        std::cout << (it - list) << " " << it->get_c() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't `a` and `b` required to be `const` for `constexpr get_a` to be legal? Or can a `constexpr` object be modifiable (I know they are private but what would happen if I asign to `a` on an `Info` object?

Comment: @ted: The members don't need to be `constexpr` because the entire object is `constexpr`. If you wanted to get a `constexpr` out of a non-`const` object but accessing a member that member needs to be `constexpr` (plus, of course, various other things defining this member).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Do you mean *by* where you wrote *but*?

Comment: Er, yes: it should have been *by*.